# Display id or name of social account on "My Logins" page

Tags: discussion, feature-request, profile-edit

If I connect a Google account it shows the email. But it doesn't show information about Facebook/[VK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VK_(service)) accounts.

> [image]

Could you display the account name or id for these social accounts? Or, even better, make it clickable and use a direct link to the account.

Comment: What is "VK" account? Never heard about it, and language in screenshot for that is unreadable for me. Russian?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Russian social network (https://vk.com). But does it matter? I guess FB and VK acc binding mechanism is the same.

Comment: Well, OpenID was dropped, you can't log in with your VK account anymore anyway as far as I can tell.. As for Facebook, not sure why no account id, but what you need it for?

Comment: @ShadowWizard on https://ru.stackoverflow.com I can login with VK acc.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I have multiple accs for dev purpose. Would be nice to see, which acc I'm using)

Comment: @ShadowWizard The SO in other language sites have a few additional options that are very popular in those countries, and are set up through OAuth paths. They're not shown on any other sites on the network. Similarly, the Launchpad OAuth option only appears on Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @animuson fair enough, thanks.